# Laravel Blade - @if( false ) results in "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

My blade template has an `@if` check which , when it turns out to be false, results in the error `"Trying to get property of non-object"`.

In the `@if`, I'm just calling a method to see if there are any results, which returns a boolean:

```
@if( Book::isUserCoauthor($book, Auth::user()->id) )

@else
```

But if it returns `false`, I get the error. Shouldn't `@if` be able to handle a `false` condition ?

The same error happens if I do:

```
@if ( false )
```

I use Laravel 4.2 .

Comment: Are you positive that line is the culprit?

Comment: and are you adding `@endif` to close out the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only an error when the condition in the `if()` clause translates to `false`, you most likely are accessing a property within the `else` block that you shouldn't.

```
@if( !Book::isUserCoauthor($book, Auth::user()->id) )
   // this seems fine
@else
   // here you are doing something bad
@endif
```

Comment: Yes! That was foolish of me. So the issue lies there somewhere (and I can probably fix it).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem you have is because you are trying to get the ID of the user even if he is not authenticated.

So you can improve the check by first checking if the user is authenticated or not, unless this whole view is protected by the `auth` middleware.

```
@if( Auth::check() && Book::isUserCoauthor($book, Auth::user()->id) )
```

Comment: I tried it but wasn't that. I get the user ID from Auth::user()->id.

Comment: I see how you get it, but `Auth::user()` returns `null` if the user is unauthenticated, hence the error that you get, trying to access `id` on a `null` object. Check if you have other usages like this on a `null` objects.